# Can't move or share files in My Files app

Tags: samsung, default-applications, samsung-galaxy-note-9, application-error, my-files

just downloaded some mp3 files and needed to move them from downloads to my music folder. not sure if its because of the new system update, but for some reason there is literally no option to move, copy, share - nothing. just move to secure folder. i tried that but all you can do is move the files out of the folder once theyre in so that was worthless. i can select them or select them to edit or select them to share. no options come up except 'move to secure folder' or 'compress'.

Answer (score 1):

went to app settings and cleared the cache for my files app. when i went back to the app i was able to see all of the file options (move, copy, delete, etc) again.